# ASP:Checkbox how to autopostback only on checked?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, checkbox, postback, autopostback

I've got a checkbox that's set up as below:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="myCheckbox" runat="Server" OnClick="showLoadingScreen(this.checked);" AutoPostBack="true" Text="Check me for more data!" />
```

The function showLoadingScreen is as below:

```
function showLoadingScreen(isChecked) {         
if (isChecked)
    {
        document.getElementById('form1').style.display='none';
        document.getElementById('img_loading').style.display='block';
    }
else { return false; }
}
```

I've added the else clause in hopes that I can get it to only post back when the checkbox is checked, but it's posting back in either case.

I've got a grid on the page (inside form1) that has a set of data loaded into it on page load, but in order to add some extra data to it I've added this checkbox (its a longer running process, so I only want to load it on demand, not upfront).  When it's checked I want to show the loading gif, postback, grab the data, and return.  If the box gets unchecked I don't want to do anything, since leaving more than enough data on the page is perfectly fine (that is to say, the data displayed upfront is a subset of the data displayed when the checkbox is checked).

Is there any way to make it so the checkbox auto posts back on checked, but not on unchecked?

**Edit:** Using Dark Falcon's suggestion, I've modified the checkbox to look like:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="myCheckbox" runat="Server" OnClick="return showLoadingScreen(this.checked);" AutoPostBack="true" Text="Include HQ Values" />
```

And the javascript to be:

```
function showLoadingScreen(checked) {         
alert(checked);
if (checked)
    {
        document.getElementById('form1').style.display='none';
        document.getElementById('img_loading').style.display='block';
        document.form1.submit();  //my own addition, to get it to post back
    }
else { return false; }
}
```

Now, it posts back on checked, but the box is not able to be unchecked anymore.  As you can see I've added an alert to show the value being passed in.  It's passing in the correct value when you uncheck the box (false), but then it somehow gets checked again.

It's not a huge issue, since there's really no reason to ever uncheck the box (since as I stated before, the dataset when checked is a superset of the unchecked dataset), but I'd still like to know why it's doing that.  Any ideas?

Comment: It does not matter what your code looks like in the VS designer.  You need to look at the markup in the browser to determine how to fix the issue.

Comment: Josh, please see my edit.  I took your advice to look at the source in the browser, and it's coming back like this: 
    <input id="myCheckbox" type="checkbox" name="myCheckbox" checked="checked" onclick="return showLoadingScreen(this.checked);" />

You can see somehow the checked="checked" got added, which I feel is how it's remaining checked in spite of the javascript returning false.  Any ideas on how to get it to NOT add that checked="checked" part?

Comment: I would rather advise to this: Uncheck the checkbox and make a callback that does not render any control. Thats ensures, that you don't have inconsistent server/client control states.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not set AutoPostBack in this case. `"AutoPostBack"` means post back to the server any time the value of this control changes... which is **NOT** what you want.

Instead, use `GetPostBackEventReference(myCheckbox,"")` to get the appropriate postback script and call this from your `showLoadingScreen` method if the checkbox is checked.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how GetPostBackEventReference works exactly.  After reading some of the other questions on SO about it, I feel that I should use it in my javascript function like: 

<%=Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(myCheckbox)%>;

But then how do I handle that server side?  In the page load?  What do I check for there?

Comment: Not sure what you mean about handling it server side?  It will just appear to be a perfectly normal postback.  Paste the code from your comment directly into showLoadingScreen(), take out AutoPostBack... and then you will have the behavior you are looking for.  Essentially, the whole problem is that you never should have had AutoPostBack set to true.  Trying to work around this is what caused the odd behavior.

Answer (score 0):

For your onclick handler, you need to do:

```
return showLoadingScreen(this.checked);
```

Comment: D'oh! I knew it was something simple. However, it didn't post back to the server on checked, only did the Javascript stuff. So I added "document.form1.submit();" to the If part of the javascript; but now the checkbox won't come unchecked, haha. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid using _doPostback as it is a hack which you will have to know what control ID is posting back and other parameters for that Javascript function from Microsoft ASP.NET.  To understand what's happening behind the scene, you have to know why there is a postback and how to prevent the postback from happening.

Here's what's happening with an ASP.NET checkbox (ASP:Checkbox) when auto-postback is set:

```html
<ASP:Checkbox runat="server" id="chkCheckbox" AutoPostback="true" onclick="return isDoPostback(this.checked);" ClientIdMode="static" ... />
```

generated HTML code is:

```html
<input type="checkbox" ... id="..." onclick="return isDoPostback(this.checked);_doPostback(...);" .../>
```

The custom onclick event is appended to the beginning of the onclick event of the checkbox.  No matter what you do, that prepended function call will execute.  Worst off, if you have a return value, the _doPostback will never get executed.

This is what you really want to do (I use a mix of jQuery and native Javascript here):

```html
var checkbox = $("#chkCheckbox");
...

checkbox .on("change", function(e)
{ if(this.checked)
 {
  var isConfirmedToContinue = confirm("Continue with Postback?");

  if(!isConfirmedToContinue)
  { this.checked = false; //Uncheck the checkbox since the user canceled out
   var onClickDelegate = this.onclick;

   if(onClickDelegate)
   { var me = this;
    this.removeEventListener("click", onClickDelegate); //Remove the onclick event so that auto-postback no longer happens

    setTimeout(function()
    {    //Add back the onclick delegate after 250ms    
                    me.addEventListener("click", onClickDelegate);
    }, 250);

    this.onclick = null; //Remove the current onclick event by nulling it out
   }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using a JS routine for checking whether it is checked, and if it is set to true, try doing:

_doPostBack(checkElementReference.name, "");

_doPostBack is responsible for performing posts to the server for controls that don't normally postback.  You have to pass the name of the element, which on the server happens to be the UniqueID property for the server-side checkbox control.

Comment: You really need to use GetPostBackEventReference() here.

Comment: No you don't.  Many people use _doPostBack; this is on the client-side, so that is appropriate (since it's what's rendered on the screen), but I understand what you are saying.  But it isn't required.